# Configurable product attribute dropdown to gridview?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I want to create product view like attached image . any one help me to create this type of products , which product type i use or any extension already have then please suggest.

example :

Color           Size

white           small medium large

red             small large

[image]